# MYsql how to log erroneous queries

Tags: mysql, error-logging

is it possible to log erroneous queries on MySQL 5.5?

At the moment i'm having a problem that i assume that some queries of my shop system run into a locking-timeout ~once a week.

But i cannot find any logs about it.

The error_log, and general_log do not log any error messages, when i run a erroneous query, for example:

```
"SELECT asdf"
```

i get an error

```
/* SQL Fehler (1054): Unknown column 'asdf' in 'field list' */
```

is it possible to log such error in any way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

<strike>You can pass it to a file and check it there:</strike>

```
mysql -u user -p 2> errors.log
```

After getting the comments, I dont think there is any way to detect the errors. You have to depend on the application layer of your code to log the errors.

Comment: the problem is that i use magento which seems to have problems with some queries, an does not catch/log them correctly, so i need a global solution

Comment: @wutzebaer:- Then I dont think there is any way to detect that. You have to stick to the application layer logging.

Comment: @wutzebaer:- Just read this: [Capturing Erroneous Queries with MySQL Proxy])(http://www.chriscalender.com/capturing-erroneous-queries-with-mysql-proxy/)

Comment: ok thank you, i thought so, because postgres has such a feature

Comment: @wutzebaer:- Indeed but MySql is different  and has some limitations ;)